# Derived class operator = error

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, instantiation, derived-class

I have an error when compiling following code. I want to basically create a derived class called SqMatrix, the square matrix, as a derived type from Matrix.  However, the compiler won't let me instantiate some customized operator.  Following is my code as matrix.h

```
#ifndef matrix_h
#define matrix_h

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

template<class T>
class Matrix {
private:
  size_t nrow;
  size_t ncol;
  std::string typenm;
  std::vector<T> *vec;
public:
  Matrix(): nrow(0), ncol(0), vec(), typenm("") {}
  Matrix(size_t nr, size_t nc, T value=T()): nrow(nr), ncol(nc), typenm(std::string(typeid(T).name()))
  { vec = new std::vector<T>(nrow*ncol, value); }
  ~Matrix()
  { delete vec; }
  size_t getnrow() const
  { return nrow; }
  size_t getncol() const
  { return ncol; }
  std::string gettypenm() const
  { return typenm; }
  T *getdata()
  { return vec->data(); }
  T *getdata() const
  { return vec->data(); }
  T &at(size_t ir, size_t ic)
{ return vec->at(ic*nrow+ir); }
  T &at(size_t ir, size_t ic) const
  { return vec->at(ic*nrow+ir); }
  virtual void resize(size_t nr, size_t nc, T value=T())
  {
    vec->resize(nr*nc, value);
    nrow = nr;
    ncol = nc;
  }
  Matrix &operator =(const Matrix &mat);
  Matrix operator +(const Matrix &mat) const;
  Matrix operator -(const Matrix &mat) const;
};

template<class T>
class SqMatrix: public Matrix<T> {
private:
  size_t ndim;
public:
  SqMatrix(): Matrix<T>(), ndim(0) {}
  SqMatrix(size_t nd, T value=T()): Matrix<T>(nd, nd, value), ndim(nd) {}
  size_t getndim() const
  { return ndim; }
  virtual void resize(size_t nd, T value=T())
  {
    Matrix<T>::resize(nd, nd, value);
    ndim = nd;
  }
  SqMatrix &operator =(const SqMatrix &sqmat)
  {
    Matrix<T>::operator =(sqmat);
    return *this;
  }
};

#endif
```

Then goes my implementation of methods, matrix.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include "precision.h"
#include "matrix.h"
#include "lapack.h"

template<class T>
Matrix<T> &Matrix<T>::operator =(const Matrix<T> &mat)
{
  try {
    if(nrow != mat.nrow) throw "Matrix::operator =: Invalid mat.nrow";
    if(ncol != mat.ncol) throw "Matrix::operator =: Invalid mat.ncol";
  }
  catch(const char *str) {
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
  }

  memcpy(vec->data(), mat.vec->data(), sizeof(T)*nrow*ncol);

  return *this;
}

template<class T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator +(const Matrix<T> &mat) const
{
  try {
    if(nrow != mat.nrow) throw "Matrix::operator +: Invalid mat.nrow";
    if(ncol != mat.ncol) throw "Matrix::operator +: Invalid mat.ncol";
  }
  catch(const char *str) {
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
  }

  Matrix<T> matsum(nrow, ncol);

  for(size_t i = 0; i < nrow*ncol; ++i)
    matsum.vec->at(i) = vec->at(i) + mat.vec->at(i);

  return matsum;
}

template<class T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator -(const Matrix<T> &mat) const
{
  try {
    if(nrow != mat.nrow) throw "Matrix::operator -: Invalid mat.nrow";
    if(ncol != mat.ncol) throw "Matrix::operator -: Invalid mat.ncol";
  }
  catch(const char *str) {
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
  }

  Matrix<T> matdif(nrow, ncol);

  for(size_t i = 0; i < nrow*ncol; ++i)
    matdif.vec->at(i) = vec->at(i) - mat.vec->at(i);

  return matdif;
}

template Matrix<dreal> &Matrix<dreal>::operator =(const Matrix<dreal> &);
template Matrix<dreal> Matrix<dreal>::operator +(const Matrix<dreal> &) const;
template Matrix<dreal> Matrix<dreal>::operator -(const Matrix<dreal> &) const;

template Matrix<dcmplx> &Matrix<dcmplx>::operator =(const Matrix<dcmplx> &);
template Matrix<dcmplx> Matrix<dcmplx>::operator +(const Matrix<dcmplx> &) const;
template Matrix<dcmplx> Matrix<dcmplx>::operator -(const Matrix<dcmplx> &) const;
```

Finally it is the main code test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include "constants.h"
#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace constants;

int main()
{
  const size_t Ndim(7);
  SqMatrix<dreal> sqmatA(Ndim,Ndim), sqmatB(Ndim,Ndim), sqmatC(Ndim,Ndim);

  for(size_t i = 0; i < Ndim; ++i)
    for(size_t j = 0; j < Ndim; ++j) {
      sqmatA.at(j, i) = (i+1) * (j+1);
      sqmatB.at(j, i) = i + j;
    }

  sqmatC = sqmatA + sqmatB;

  return 0;
}
```

It is weird that the compiler complains:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:20: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘sqmatC = Matrix<T>::operator+(const Matrix<T>&) const [with T = double](((const Matrix<double>&)((const Matrix<double>*)(& sqmatB.SqMatrix<double>::<anonymous>))))’
matrix.h:62: note: candidates are: SqMatrix<T>& SqMatrix<T>::operator=(const SqMatrix<T>&) [with T = double]
```

Clearly it is due to the operator = for the derived class SqMatrix. I actually implemented operator = for SqMatrix, why it still complains, or what is the actual mistake I made?

Thanks in advance!

Yi

Comment: Could you cut down your code to a minimal example that reproduces the error?

Comment: `memcpy(vec->data(), mat.vec->data(), sizeof(T)*nrow*ncol);`  If T is non-POD, this won't work out too well.  Also, if you changed to this in your `Matrix` class: `std::vector<T> vec;` then there is no need for an `operator=`.

Comment: To add, use a `std::vector<T>`, not a `std::vector<T>*` in your `Matrix` class, and *all* of those assignment operators are unnecessary, including the ones in the derived classes.  You're doing work the compiler should be doing automatically.  In addition, all of those assignment operators and no copy constructor(s)?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `operator+` in your subclass `SqMatrix`. That's why your matrix sum `sqmatA + sqmatB` uses the `operator+` of the generic class `Matrix`, which returns a `Matrix`, which therefore cannot be passed on to your specific `operator=` in your subclass `SqMatrix`.

Answer (score 0):

For the compilation error:

The '+' operator returns an object of class 'Matrix'. You did not define an assignment operator in 'SqMatrix' that takes a 'Matrix' object.

On the over hand, making square matrix being a subclass of matrix may or may not be the best idea:

- you carry a superfluous member variable around (ndim) and instead of square matrix being dimension and data, its dimension, data, and inherited x and y dimension
- there are no methods of matrix overloaded to take advantage of the squareness
- you create ambiguity - one can create a normal matrix which is square to (because it happens to have same x & y dimension)

Being a square matrix is better suite to be a (computed) property of a matrix.